# Unity crashes without any error or warning on project opening

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

First of all, I don't know If this is the right place for that question. I've searched everywhere or asked Unity Help Forum but nothing helped.

On Unity Hub, when I click my project to open, Unity starting screen shows up and after 27 seconds (this is the exact time) it stops and disappears immediately without any warnings or errors.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using the UnityHub 3.0 or 2.x  (or in simple words: is it dark ^^) ?

Comment: Yes, It is 3.0.0 @derHugo

Comment: I have this sometimes but only for 2021 .. turned out it was an issue with the license .. for me e.g. only happens when I'm in VPN ^^

Comment: I've had issues with network share paths not working.  Solution there was to move the project off the network share onto a local drive.  Those virtual drives were setup by our IT at work, I cannot speak for the exact configuration of it.

Comment: @hijinxbassist in general having them on a network drive wouldn't make you happy regarding a) fileIO performance and b) simultaneous access of the project (it could only be open once at a time ^^

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had 3 different scenes opened when Unity started crashing. Instead of opening the project from the Hub, which loads the last project state (i.e. the 3 scenes at once), I tried opening a single scene (by double clicking the scene file from Explorer), and I could get in. In this case I think the crashes had something to do with baked lighting so I opened the scenes one by one, cleared the baked data, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the issue in my personal case. I was using the internet through a proxy server and somehow that was causing the issue. As soon as I switched to my normal non-proxy internet, the issue got resolved and I could open unity projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still having this problem, but in my case, I deleted the following directories from my project folder and then re-opened the project.

`/Library`
`/Logs`
`/Temp`
`/UserSettings`

Unity reinstalled the editor specific files and project packages and it opened without a problem :)

Comment: same problem, but it did not work.